# Unresolved constraint when trying to export a simple interface

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, bundle

I'm trying to take the first steps in familiarizing myself to OSGI framework. 
However, I'm not even able to start the bundle which only exports one package, nothing more.
The error the framework shows sounds ridiculous to me as I read it as 'In order to start your bundle I need to resolve openjsip.service.locationservice package. 
But this package comes from my bundle !
Anyway, I think I'm wrong, but I can't grasp the problem, could somebody help me ?

```
ERROR: Bundle openjsip.locationservice [6] Error starting file:////tmp/locationservice-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle openjsip.locationservice [6]: Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=openjsip.service.locationservice)(version>=1.0.0)))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle openjsip.locationservice [6]: Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=openjsip.service.locationservice)(version>=1.0.0))
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is my MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1348338100498
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_05
Built-By: devel
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: locationservice
Bundle-SymbolicName: openjsip.locationservice
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: openjsip.service.locationservice;uses:="javax.sip.header
 ,javax.sip";version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT"
Import-Package: javax.sip;version="[1.2,2)",javax.sip.header;version="[1
 .2,2)"
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message doesn't seem to match the MANIFEST.MF you have posted. Is it possible that you have rebuilt it in-between?

The error message says that your bundle *imports* the package `openjsip.service.locationservice`, and that import could not be resolved. However according to the manifest you only import `javax.sip` and `javax.sip.header`. Therefore this error message could not have come from the bundle manifest posted.

Comment: Many thanks, Neil, I took my attention to the place where my bundle is taken from. It is /tmp instead of <project_home>/target (I'm using Maven). When I looked inside the MANIFEST is indeed totally different from what I posted. 
IntelliJ IDEA is playing tricks on me, it magically create this file in /tmp and passes it to OSGI framework. Now I need to investigate what's happening...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for help, the issue was really with IDEA configuration, where it creates MANIFEST.MF by itself using facet configuration (which I left empty relying on apache maven plugin). For some reason it ignores this plugin or can't work in pair with it yet.
The resolution was to tell it 'Use predefined MANIFEST.MF from target/classes/META-INF'.

Thanks again.